# Change drupal standard messages like "You have just used your one time login link"

Tags: 7, users

I'm having trouble with changing drupal default messages.

Like for example when you register you get an email with a one time login link (I know how to change this email text) and when you click on the link you get the message

> This is a one-time login for username and will expire on ... .
>
> Click on this button to log in to the site and change your password.
>
> This login can be used only once.

But how can I change this text? Another example is:

> You have just used your one-time login link. It is no longer necessary to use this link to log in. Please change your password.

How can I change these texts?

Comment: Please don't use code blocks for non-code content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module. If you have more strings to change.

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> **Features**
>
> - Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
> - Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
> - Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the
>   Locale module
> - Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of
>   overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need
>   a few easy text changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a little question, what means the Context? You have the original string, replacement string and then context, but what is context?

Comment: @nielsv Sorry I didn't get you what you mean? Can you elaborate? If it is different question please ask that as a new question instead of in comment!.